# Serialization of boost::shared_ptr through a custom archive

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, shared-ptr, archive

I'm trying to serialize a boost::shared_ptr to a custom archive. The main problem I'm facing is that the boost::serialization code for shared_ptr requires the archive to have both a 'reset' and an 'append' method.

Does anyone know where these methods are documented? The Archive Concept in boost says nothing about these methods (or at least I wasn't able to find anything), and could not even find the declarations of such methods on text_iarchive (or base classes). However, usage of text_iarchive is possible without any problems.

On the other hand, with my own archive the code would not compile:

```
class my_iarchive : public boost::archive::detail::common_iarchive<my_iarchive> {
    // load, load_binary, load_override, etc. ...
};
```

**/usr/include/boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp:139:5: error: ‘class my_iarchive’ has no member named ‘reset’**

Answer ( courtesy of Tawnos )

```
#include <boost/archive/shared_ptr_helper.hpp>

class my_iarchive : public boost::archive::detail::common_iarchive<my_iarchive>,
                    public boost::archive::detail::shared_ptr_helper {
     //load, load archive, etc.
};
```

Comment: Does this help? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0_beta1/boost/archive/shared_ptr_helper.hpp It has definitions for both reset and append.